# Entity Framework One To Many one sided join

Tags: linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [MIS].[Logging](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MachineName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LogSource] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LogSourceVersion] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LogLevel] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LogMessage] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LogDetailLocation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Logging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))


CREATE TABLE [MIS].[LoggingLevels](
    [LoggingLevelName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LoggingLevelValue] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LoggingLevels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoggingLevelName] ASC
))
```

And These two classes for the tables:

```
public class Logging
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string LogSource { get; set; }
    public string LogSourceVersion { get; set; }
public string LogDetailLocation { get; set; }
public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }

//public string LogLevel { get; set; }
public LoggingLevel Level { get; set; }
}

public class LoggingLevel
{
    public int LoggingLevelValue { get; set; }
    public string LoggingLevelName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is defining the relationship using the fluent API, as you can see there is a foreign key from Logging to LoggingLevel, but I don't want the corresponding collection of logs on the LoggingLevel class.  I've tried a number of combinations of the following, including `.WithRequiredDependant` and `.WithRequiredPrincipal`:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Logging>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.Level)
                .WithOptional()
                .Map(l => l.MapKey("LoggingLevelName"));
```

This never ends up getting the join correct, here is data from the LoggingLevel table, and some sample rows from the logging table.

```
LoggingLevelName LoggingLevelValue
---------------- -----------------
ALL              -2147483648
DEBUG            30000
INFO             40000
WARN             60000
ERROR            70000
FATAL            110000
OFF              2147483647


id          MachineName LogSource LogSourceVersion LogLevel   LogMessage LogDetailLocation LogTime
----------- ----------- --------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------- -----------------------
115170694   redacted    redacted  17               INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:00:02.420
115170695   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:00:03.587
115170696   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:01:01.357
115170697   redacted    redacted  NULL             INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:01:01.357
115170698   redacted    redacted  10               INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:01:01.933
115170699   redacted    redacted  17               INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:01:33.320
115170700   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:02:29.990
115170701   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:02:30.000
115170702   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:02:30.040
115170703   redacted    redacted  (null)           INFO       redacted   redacted          2013-01-29 04:02:30.243
```

Here is sample linq query I'm trying to run:

```
    var results = (from log in db.Loggings
                   where log.Level.LoggingLevelValue >= 60000
                         && log.LogTime >= filterDate
                   orderby log.LogTime descending
                   select log);
    return results.ToList();
```

---

Update results from using :

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Logging>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.Level).WithMany();
```

Here is the SQL this generates when running my query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[MachineName] AS [MachineName], 
[Project1].[LogSource] AS [LogSource], 
[Project1].[LogSourceVersion] AS [LogSourceVersion], 
[Project1].[LogDetailLocation] AS [LogDetailLocation], 
[Project1].[LogTime] AS [LogTime], 
[Project1].[LogMessage] AS [LogMessage], 
[Project1].**[Level_LoggingLevelName]** AS [Level_LoggingLevelName]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[MachineName] AS [MachineName], 
    [Extent1].[LogSource] AS [LogSource], 
    [Extent1].[LogSourceVersion] AS [LogSourceVersion], 
    [Extent1].[LogDetailLocation] AS [LogDetailLocation], 
    [Extent1].[LogTime] AS [LogTime], 
    [Extent1].[LogMessage] AS [LogMessage], 
    [Extent1].**[Level_LoggingLevelName]** AS [Level_LoggingLevelName]
    FROM  [MIS].[Logging] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [MIS].[LoggingLevels] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Level_LoggingLevelName] = [Extent2].[LoggingLevelName]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[LoggingLevelValue] >= @p__linq__0) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[LogTime] AS datetime2) >= @p__linq__1)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[LogTime] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0=60000,@p__linq__1='2013-02-04 00:00:00'
```

I put ** around the fields in error in the query, bold doesn't work in code sections though.

Here is my full fluent API configuration:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Logging>().ToTable("Logging", "MIS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Logging>().HasKey(l => l.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<LoggingLevel>().ToTable("LoggingLevels", "MIS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<LoggingLevel>().HasKey(ll => ll.LoggingLevelName);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProblemResolution>().ToTable("ProblemResolutions", "MIS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProblemResolution>().HasKey(r => r.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Logging>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.Level).WithMany();
```

Comment: Code first should generate the equivalent of the 2 table as defined ?

Comment: I didn't generate tables, it's an existing database, but no, I don't want code first to generate anything.

Comment: I am aware I can do this differently using a join from LogLevel to LoggingLevelName, but I want to learn how to do this with foreign key and property on the class.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand what exactly your are trying to do

Comment: using the tables I've defined, and the classes for them, I'm trying to get the linq query at the bottom to run without generating invalid SQL.

Comment: The POCO classes dont match the Table definitions. And the table defintion doesnt have a foreign key constraint . Yet the Fluent api suggests it should.   Im confused .

Comment: What do you mean they don't match, what doesn't match?  Is a foreign key constraint necessary on the table in order to add relationships with the fluent api?

Comment: No thats not necessary.  But the chicken and egg story.. DB first code first.  And what the actual outcome should be .  I could answer if I could understand the question. perhaps someone else can understand what you asking. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you want to create a one-to-many relationship, right?

One `LoggingLevel` can have many `Logging` and one `Logging` is required to have one `LoggingLevel`.

The way you are configuring the relationship, will make EF create it as a one-to-one.

To make it correctly become one-to-many, you have to call `WithMany` instead of `WithOptional`:

```
HasRequired(l => l.Level).WithMany().Map(p => p.MapKey("LogLevel"))
```

Since the column used as the foreign key is called LogLevel in the database, you have to tell EF by using the `Map` method, and call the `MapKey` method with the correct column name.

Otherwise it generates the column name by convention. It uses the navigation property name and the name of the key property of the target type, and appends the values.

In your case this results in `Level_LoggingLevelName`, which is not right. So you have to map the column name manually.

Comment: That still doesn't generate the SQL correctly, it tries to query a column Level_LoggingLevelName, see my update above.

Comment: The mapkey did the trick, thanks.  Do you know of a good site for documentation on this, I googled but all I got was the basic FK relationship stuff from MSDN, nothing on doing this kind of mapping.

Comment: I have the book _Programming Entity Framework: Code First_ where stuff like this is explained. I don't know of any sites, sorry..

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll check out the book.